# Build OSGI declarative services with Maven

Tags: java, service, osgi

I have a problem to build my OSGI service with Maven. My `pom.xml` :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
          <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
          <Service-Component>OSGI-INF/activator.xml</Service-Component>
          <Import-Package>org.osgi.framework</Import-Package>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I build with *Maven install* there is generated .jar file, but OSGI-INF folder not exist. I use Eclipse and m2e plugin. Why OSGI-INF folder is not in the .jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you want to use bnd's internal annotation framework, you wouldn't need the dependency on the felix scr plugin.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>biz.aQute</groupId>
        <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.50.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Once you do that, you can tell bnd to generate the Declarative services xml with this configuration option to the maven-bundle-plugin:

```
    <Service-Component>*</Service-Component>
```

That will generate the OSG-INF stuff for you. The annotations are slightly different, they're documented here: http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Components

Also, you're imports look really funky, I would recommend this:

```
    <instructions>
         <Export-Package>{local-packages};version="${project.version}"</Export-Package>
         <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
         <Private-Package>{local-packages}</Private-Package>
         <Service-Component>*</Service-Component>
    </instructions>
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can use my ready activator.xml without annotations?

Comment: well, yes, but the annotations are really nice, auto-generate everything for you ;)

Comment: so in my project we had a similar problem, try this: <_include>OSGI-INF/activator.xml</_include>

Comment: you may also need to add a resources section to your build in maven to get the resource to be picked up. I'm assuming that your OSGI-INF directory is in src/main/resources

Comment: Indeed when I put OSGI-INF in src/main/resources it works. Thank you for answers.

Comment: You should just be able change the artifactId from `bndlib` to `annotation` - it's a smaller jar, so fewer irrelevant classes appear in your auto-complete.